# CDI: Obtaining InjectionPoint when producing a scoped bean

Tags: java, cdi

whats the easiest way to obtain the InjectionPoint when your producer method is producing a scoped bean? For some reason the spec does only allow injection of the InjectionPoint when you are producing scoped beans.
Is there an easy way to do that or some kind of bolg entry or tutorial for that?

For clarifiaction, here is what Id like to do, but what is forbidden by the spec:

```
@Produces
@RequestScoped
@MyAnnotation    
private MyObject produce(InjectioPoint ip){
....
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's imaging that what you'd like to do is possible. You have an `@ApplicationScoped` bean defined:

```
@Produces
@ApplicationScoped
String produceMyString(InjectionPoint ip) {}
```

And you have two injection points for that bean:

```
@Inject
String myString1;

@Inject
String myString2;
```

As the bean is `ApplicationScoped`, the producer method will get called only once. Which leads to the conclusion that it is impossible as the container cannot choose what injection point to use as a parameter of the producer method.

This explains why accessing the `InjectionPoint` metadata forces the bean to be `@Dependent`. Stated another way, the CDI specification forbids that behavior because it leads to a contradiction and not because of an arbitrary choice.

Comment: Hmm, I might be wrong here, but as far as I understand the scope only specifies the lifecycle of the injected bean. 
In this case the producer would be called once for each injection point during the lifecycle, but is not required to return the same bean for each injection point. I will write a testcase for this, and post the results.

Comment: Turns out you were right; the producer method only gets called once.In this case im curious if its possible to change the behaviour. I saw that Omnifaces seems to have manged this, see https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/cdi/param/DynamicParamValueProducer.java

Comment: In this example the scope of the bean is `@Dependent` as returned by the `getScope` method: https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/cdi/param/DynamicParamValueProducer.java#L88